# use "choose file" input to change div backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change a div background with user's picture, from his local machine. But it doesn't seem to work for me.

```js
$("#addPhoto").change(function() {
  var fileName = $(this).value;
  $("#myPic").css({
    "backgroundImage": "url('" + fileName + "')"
  });
});
```

```css
#myPic {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -7%;
  left: -4%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="addPhoto" />
<div id="myPic"></div>
```

The console gives me "file not found" error.

Comment: You can't use `file:///` protocols for your background image. Are you running this on a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's more an anwser to the other responses, but **don't use a FileReader**.

That will load the File's data three times in memory for nothing, will create an overly long string that will stand in both the DOM and CSSOM for long time, while you can achieve the same result with loading this data only once.

To do so, create a Blob URI from your File, thanks to the *[URL.createObectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)* method. This will return a string that you'll be able to use later as an URI, pointing directly to the File on disk.

Last added benefit: its generation is synchronous.

```js
$("#addPhoto").change(function() {
  var file = this.files[0];
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  $("#myPic").css({
    "backgroundImage": "url('" + url + "')"
  });
});
```

```css
#myPic {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -7%;
  left: -4%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="addPhoto" />
<div id="myPic"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) can do that easily:

```js
$("#addPhoto").change(function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        $("#myPic").css({
            "background-image": "url('" + reader.result + "')"
        });
    }
    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {}
});
```

```css
#myPic {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -7%;
  left: -4%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="addPhoto" />
<div id="myPic"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `file:///` protocols for your background image. However, if you read the file on the client side using `FileReader` and convert into `data` URI scheme, you may be able to do this.

```js
$(function() {
  function getBase64(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function() {
      console.log(reader.result);
      $("#myPic").css({
        "backgroundImage": "url('" + reader.result + "')"
      });
    };
    reader.onerror = function(error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
  }
  $("#addPhoto").change(function() {
    getBase64(this.files[0]);
  });
});
```

```css
#myPic {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -7%;
  left: -4%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="addPhoto" />
<div id="myPic"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('change',"#addPhoto",function(){
    readURL(this);
});


function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#myPic').css('background', 'url('+e.target.result+')');
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```css
#myPic{
height:250px;
width:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="addPhoto" />


<div id="myPic">
</div>
```

Comment: Don't spoon feed users. Tell what you have changed. Add some informational text.